# Approach to a multi-view object classfication problem

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm currently working on a common object classification and I use a CNN to do that. Each instance has 3 images with differents views (front, back, side) and I would like to use this to improve my network, so I want to build a multiple input network. I'm wondering if I should :

- Build 1 network with 3 different pipeline convolutional, merge their result and then use a softmax.
- Build 1 network with shared weigth for features part and then softmax

Comment: Cross-posted: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/29038/8560, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/333246/2921.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find out the answer to your question is to **simply try out both approaches and see which works better**.

This may sound stupid or obvious, but the architecture of the network is simply another "hyperparameter" which you need to tune and every dataset may need something else.

That said, I would personally bet on a combination of these: In the first half of the net, share the weights between three pipelines, then concatenate them and apply several additional conv. layers before the final softmax.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I don't understand quite 'share the weights between three pipelines', because either i have 3 pipeline, either i share 1 pipeline for 3 channels.